# menu does not appear on mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, menubar

When I open my site in mobile, the menu bar is hidden by the layer slider. Also, the logo should appear on the header, but its not.

```
.header-wrapper{ background-color:#0073ff; position: relative;
height: 60px;
}

div.title-item-wrapper h2.title-item-header{ color: #0073ff; }

.logo-wrapper{ padding-top:2px; }

h3.gdl-header-title{ color:#0073ff; }

div.package-search-select{ padding-right: 21px; }

a.gdl-button.small{ padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; font-size: 14px;
}
```

This is my css for web. how can I modify this for mobile.

This is my site http://185.105.4.132/~zen/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responsive menubar can be done using **Bootstrap** Framework.
**DEMO**

https://jsfiddle.net/DhwaniSanghvi/novgts5c/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="pull-left"><img src="http://185.105.4.132/~zen/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Zen-Logo-Small13.png"></div>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
   <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>     
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: yes.. I know that. But how do I install it in wordpress. Do I upload the bootstrap in wp-content ? 
and there are many index.php files, which file should I choose to edit the mark up. 
I am sorry, I am kinda newbie to this.

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/responsive-wordpress-bootstrap-theme-tutorial This is complete guide how to make responsive theme or layout in woodpress

Answer (score 0):

To adapt your page for mobile you can do a few things

1. Take a look at [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)
2. Use a framework like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)
3. Use % values instead of px

Answer (score 0):

Issue is slide-show is overlaying on menu.
For mobile add

```
header-area-wrapper{position: relative;}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: try this :
@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
.header-area-wrapper {
    position: relative !important;
}